# Div center in the screen and next to it another inline div

Tags: css, html, layout, center

I'm trying to have an horizontally centered div with the screen and another div aligned at its side (this is the div that I want to make "movible", to float to the maximum right of the screen for example. 
The problem is that the centered div always ends up exiting of the screen center.

Thanks!

Comment: JSFiddle please: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

I do think this is the effect you are describing I use

```
position: absolute
```

to achieve it. Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BcsVC/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
body{ /* or parent element */
    text-align: center;
}

.text{
    font-weight: 800;
    color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.text:after{
    content: "side text";
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    font-weight: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
    left: 100%;

}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6wAuF/1/)